# Invalid type for implements System.Schedulable Class

Tags: apex, class, permissions, scheduled-apex, type

I have the following class which I try to schedule from the anonymous window but this gives the error:

> invalid type:abc_RiskSchedulerProcessor

**Class**

```
global class abc_RiskSchedulerProcessor implements System.Schedulable {
    global abc_RiskSchedulerProcessor() {

    }
    global void execute(System.SchedulableContext SC) {

    }
}
```

**Anonymous window**

```
Datetime sysTime = System.now();
sysTime = sysTime.addSeconds(5);
String chron_exp = '' 
                   + sysTime.second() + ' ' 
                   + sysTime.minute() + ' ' 
                   + sysTime.hour() + ' '
                   + sysTime.day() + ' ' 
                   + sysTime.month() + ' ? ' + sysTime.year();
abc_RiskSchedulerProcessor scheduler = new abc_RiskSchedulerProcessor();
System.schedule('RiskScheduler', chron_exp, scheduler);
```

Comment: If this is your exact code, I don't see an issue. I literally copy pasted the snippet here and tried replicating, and it just worked fine.

Comment: Error states that you do not have the class named `abc_RiskSchedulerProcessor` in your org, double check if you are running script in right org's dev console. I ran the code in dev console without creating that class; gave same error as you.

Comment: @Raul You should add your comments as an answer as that seem to be the reason here.

Comment: @Raul the class is in the org as I can schedule it in the declarative way could this be perhaps that the class version is incorrect?

Comment: Is this class in a **managed package** by chance?

Comment: @JayantDas, OP was not clear enough to specify if the code was from a managed package as suggested by our beloved sfdcfox; hence did not add it as an answer. Thanks and happy helping!

Comment: @sfdcfox This clas is indeed in a managed package

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Apex Code, a class in a managed package has a "namespace." This is a prefix used by the platform to allow a managed package to have the same class name (and other things, like objects, fields, triggers, etc) as a class in your org. To use such a class in Apex, you need to include its namespace prefix. You can find this detail on the class' detail page, or by querying the [ApexClass](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_apexclass.htm) object. Once you find the namespace, you need to add it in your code:

```
Datetime sysTime = System.now();
sysTime = sysTime.addSeconds(5);
String chron_exp = '' 
                   + sysTime.second() + ' ' 
                   + sysTime.minute() + ' ' 
                   + sysTime.hour() + ' '
                   + sysTime.day() + ' ' 
                   + sysTime.month() + ' ? ' + sysTime.year();
theNS.abc_RiskSchedulerProcessor scheduler = new theNS.abc_RiskSchedulerProcessor();
System.schedule('RiskScheduler', chron_exp, scheduler);
```

Where `theNS` is the namespace of the class.